# BAML Error When Animating

Tags: wpf, animation, baml

I have the following code in a WPF 4 project, linked to an imagebox. I have four other similar instances of it that work perfectly. Why is this one throwing that vague "BAML" error we all hate (it points to the animations)? FYI, I'm using VB.net in code behind.

```
<Image Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,83,0,0" Name="Spinefish" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="323" Source="/VBP-WORD4WORD;component/Images/IMG-SPINEFISH1.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" />
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:60" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].X">
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-1000" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:25" Value="-1000" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:30" Value="1000" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:55" Value="1000" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:60" Value="-1000" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:60" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX">
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:29.9" Value="1" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:30" Value="-1" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:59.9" Value="-1" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:60" Value="1" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyTime="0:0:60"` and `Duration="0:0:60"` do not exist, the seconds range is from 0 to 59 only, change those to `0:1:0`.

Comment: Awesome! Tried to put an upvote, but I made a mistake and can't do it now. TY for the awesome answer.